# How to loop my audio file?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to loop my audio file in UWP. Here is my class:

```
public class NuriSound
{

    public enum SoundEfxEnum
    {
        Click,
        Dice,
        Theme,
    }

    public class SoundEffects
    {
        private Dictionary<SoundEfxEnum, MediaElement> _effects;

        public SoundEffects()
        {
            _effects = new Dictionary<SoundEfxEnum, MediaElement>();
            LoadEfx();
        }

        private async void LoadEfx()
        {
            _effects.Add(SoundEfxEnum.Theme, await LoadSoundFile("theme.wav"));
            _effects.Add(SoundEfxEnum.Click, await LoadSoundFile("click.wav"));
            _effects.Add(SoundEfxEnum.Dice, await LoadSoundFile("dice.wav"));
        }

        private async Task<MediaElement> LoadSoundFile(string v)
        {
            MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();

            snd.AutoPlay = false;
            StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("sounds");
            StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(v);
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            return snd;
        }

        public async Task Play(SoundEfxEnum efx)
        {
            var mediaElement = _effects[efx];
            mediaElement.Play();

        }

        public async Task Stop(SoundEfxEnum efx)
        {
            var mediaElement = _effects[efx];
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }

        public async Task Loop(SoundEfxEnum efx)
        {
            var mediaElement = _effects[efx];
            // ...

        }

    }

}
```

I want to use task "Loop", and call it like this:
"await App.MyAppSounds.Loop(NuriSound.SoundEfxEnum.Theme)" ?
What I need to write to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IsLooping` property in the `mediaElement`.

```
mediaElement.IsLooping = true;
if (mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused || mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped) 
{
     mediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: I use it on click event for my button

Comment: IsLooping works in my task LoadSoundFile. I just created new one, for looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `MediaElement's MediaEnded event` and play the music again.

Comment: You means "mediaElement.MediaEnded += MediaEndedEventHandler;" ?

Comment: Ok, how must I set this "MediaEndedEventHandler" in my class ?

Comment: After mediaElement Play() you can add mediaElement.MediaEnded+=Handler. And inside handler play the song again.